# Inverse Laplace Transform and the Unit Step Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I need to find the inverse Laplace transform of the following function:

$$ F(s) = \frac{(s-2)e^{-s}}{s^2-4s+3} $$

I completed the square on the bottom and got the following:

$$ F(s) = (e^{-s}) \frac{(s-2)}{(s-2)^2+3} $$

Disregarding the $e^{-s}$ for the moment, I have a function of the following form:

$$ \frac{s-a}{(s-a)^2+b^2} = e^{at}\cos{bt}$$

That, combined with the fact that I have a function of the following form:

$$ e^{-cs}F(s) = u_c(t)f(t-c) \text{, where } u_c(t) \text{ is the unit step function}$$

Should give me the following:

$$ f(t) = u_1(t)e^{2(t-1)}\cos{(\sqrt3t-\sqrt3)} $$

But the answer in the back is

$$ f(t) = u_1(t)e^{2(t-1)}\cosh(t-1) $$

Are these the same thing, or did I do something wrong? What's the best way to go about figuring that out? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the step $$\color{red}{ F(s) = (e^{-s}) \frac{(s-2)}{(s-2)^2+3}}$$ there is a little mistake, since $s^2-4s+3=(s^2-4s+4)-1=(s-2)^2-1\neq(s-2)^2+3$

Comment: Ah, yes. That changes everything. Sloppy algebra on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe 
\begin{align*}
\frac{(s-2)e^{-s}}{s^2-4s+3}&=\frac{(s-2)e^{-s}}{(s-2)^2-1^2}\\
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{(s-2)e^{-s}}{s^2-4s+3}\right\}&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{(s-2)e^{-s}}{(s-2)^2-1^2}\right\}\\
\end{align*}
Since 
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{(s-2)}{(s-2)^2-1^2}\right\}= e^{2t}\cosh{t}$$
It follows
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{(s-2)e^{-s}}{s^2-4s+3}\right\}=\mathcal{U}_1(t)e^{2(t-1)}\cosh{(t-1)}$$